# Css with multiple classes not working when one is :hover

Tags: html, css, mouseover

I'm trying to build a css class which has the same style of another one with the `:hover` property. 
The problem is that only when I'm over the element the style is applied and not where I specify the new class.

This is my try:

```
.body_cal .cell_cal:hover .bg_cal, 
.body_cal .cell_cal .bg_cal .hover_cal {
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition: .3s ease-in;
}
```

I would like that by adding the `hover_cal` class I'd get the same result as moving the mouse over it.

Comment: Please add your html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same effect by placing `.hover_cal` in the same order as the `.cell_call:hover` pseudo class:

```
.body_cal .cell_cal:hover .bg_cal, 
.body_cal .hover_cal .bg_cal{
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition: .3s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: It's working thank you! It was also crucial to don't repeat .cell_cal